# I am working on Android Project where i am not able to decide which database i should use(I am beginner in android programing))

Tags: android, database

I am developing an android project where I want to store images and details about that image.As it will take large storage for images on large scale, I am looking to store them on cloud and link that image with details in the database.So I am confused on which database I should use(like SQLite or MySQL or any other?).

As they say----
SQLite -- is faster but I think it's not convenient to use it for this project(as it will be a large one).
And I am not sure about MySQL (can I use it effectively?).
Or is there any other effective way to approach it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: In android you only have one database, that is sqlite. Other than that you can use [Realm](https://realm.io/news/realm-for-android/).

Comment: You can use any networked database, through webservices.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, you don't have mysql on android, you only have sqlite.

You can use an ORM: http://greenrobot.org/android/android-orm-performance-2016/ and see what best suits you.

- Are you worried about write speed? probably go with GreenDao / Realm.
- Are you worried about read speed? go with Realm.
- Are you worried about size? don't go with Realm.
- Do you want a noSQL DB? Go with Realm
- Do you have a lot of joins? Go with an ORM

Here https://github.com/olivierg13/GreenDao-vs-Realm you can see that Realm was faster in all tests, but from my experience the write speed difference wasn't that big.